# Oracle DB: How to check users who have used up storage

Tags: oracle

I have a homework question where i need to run a query on DBA_TS_QUOTAS data dictionary view that should display users who have used up storage. How do I write this check condition on my query?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your current query look like?

Comment: I am not sure what it is supposed to be but I'm assuming if i could be like:
Select * from dba_ts_quotas where Bytes > Max_Bytes?

Comment: Please try that, and then edit your question, add that query, post the results (an error or unexpected result).

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a homework assignment I'm not going to  answer your question but will provide you with some hints.

In dba_ts_quota the column max_bytes = -1 means no quota so you would want to look at the bytes column and look for bytes >0 if you want to exclude any users who have not used any space at all. Remove >0 if you want all users.